# Spring Pagination : param mapping and page result issues

Tags: spring-boot, pagination, spring-data

I want to use the Spring tooling to implement my pagination. I currently have no underlying database and want to feed the request from a dummy list provided in pages. The request in the REST controller looks like:

```
@Override
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Page<ComponentDto> getComponents(@RequestParam("searchTerm") Optional<String> searchTerm, Pageable pageRequest) {
    return componentService.getComponents(searchTerm, pageRequest);
```

When I curl or use swagger to send a request, the default values for the pagable are always used, not the given request params for size and page and sorting and so on. 
The request URL looks like:

```
http://localhost:8090/zoo-service/v1/components?pageNumber=2&pageSize=2
```

Is there anything required to get the mapping done automatically? Also another issue is, if I use two int params for the page and the size and use the static PageRequest call to provide the Pageable to my service. The evaluation and page creation looks like:

```
if (searchTerm.isPresent() && StringUtils.isNoneBlank(searchTerm.get())) {
        List<ComponentDto> list  = componentMockProvider.getMockedComponents().stream().filter(it -> it.getName().contains(searchTerm.get())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        result = new PageImpl<ComponentDto>(list, pageRequest, list.size());
    }
    else{
        result = new PageImpl<ComponentDto>(componentMockProvider.getMockedComponents(), pageRequest, componentMockProvider.getMockedComponents().size());
    }
    return result;
```

The Page always delivers the full content list, but the pagination information is correct. So my list contains 6 elements, I want the second page and the page size is 3, the page knows this information bis the delivered content is still the full list with 6 elements.

I hope you get what my problem is an thanks for help!

Comment: Whats your pagination params? page and size ? Can you post the URL you hit

Comment: Added the request URL. Also swagger provides me more params to specify like offset and paged and sort

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how I have to handle the pagination. For the first problem I only had a swagger issue which provided pageSize and pageNumber as params. This was the problem for the first issue that the Pageable could not resolve the params. For the second issue I hat do implement the computation of the content myself and pass the computed list as content to the PageImpl constructor.